# Triage queue audit - ambiguous result

Tags: discussion, support

I was recently tested on the following triage queue question and failed:
[image: Looks ok?]

I am new to the review queues, but I'm struggling to understand the exact reason for the failure.

The test was relating to signalr support on windows server 2016.  It had no question regarding **programming** with the signalr library, therefore I marked it for migration to ServerFault, rather than keeping it on StackOverflow.

Could someone provide feedback on why I should have marked this as "looks ok", so i can improve my reviewing in future.

Comment: For reference, the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766626/signalr-supported-platforms

Comment: Don't know who downvoted, but it wasn't me - I'd also mark it as you did, and fail the audit

Comment: Migrating to Server Fault wouldn't have been my choice. Don't expect an Ops guy to know if your dev lib runs on their server ...

Comment: @rene So if you'd choose to migrate that question, would you fail the audit too?

Comment: @AlonEitan yes. Because migrating is a close action. Due to the 5 upvotes and no down votes that question is considered good. We have to discuss here if we agree with that.

Comment: Should we also take into consideration the current votes/comments, not just the question itself? This question is partially relevant because of the library, but if users upvote an irrelevant question I understand that it should be flagged regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowing if a library is supported in a certain configuration is a programming task often encountered by programmers. In that sense such questions are on-topic.

I'm not overly thrilled by that question though. It would have been much more valuable if it had failed to run on that operating system, so the answer could have elaborated what was needed to make it work.

Keep in mind that a successful migration of a question to an other site does require that the question is on-topic on the target. I honestly doubt if the question would fly on Server Fault. Don't expect the operations people that run your data center to know if all the libraries and tooling you bring to their server will actually work. That is not their job. They only make sure that what you coded, runs, scales and is secure, 24/7.

I'm not sure what the best way forward is. Normally when users get tripped by an audit I tend to vote on the question to get it out of the pool for possible audits. In this case I think the question is OK-ish. I keep my votes for other posts. The audit did its job correctly, sorry.

Comment: `I honestly doubt if the question would fly on Server Fault` this is a very helpful snippet!  I hadn't considered the question's validity on the target site, it also seems somewhat irrelevant to SF.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: The question seems to be "Does Windows Server supports this thing?", I'm not entirely sure SF guys wouldn't know.

Comment: @Braiam oh, if they can, even more respect ...

Comment: Speaking as a long-time SF member, I agree that it's the devs' job to choose libraries etc that will work on the target system. The devs should have a test environment that is close enough to the target that they should know what works. (It *may* be the ops' job to then help install those libraries, at least unless you've got good devops processes in place.)